# #postsharp Unable to compile after adding PostSharp.Community nuget package (on a Mac)

Tags: postsharp

I'm using a Mac with Visual Studio 2019.  I've added nuget packages: PostSharp and PostSharp.Community.  I have NOT changed any code.  I wasn't NOT prompted to select a license.  I'm simply trying to compile, and I get the following errors.

> /var/tmp/postsharp/cache/DependencyRestore/6.0.101/net6.0-sdk6.0.101-osx-x64--ps6.10.6.0-cf0d89f.deps.proj
> : error NU3034: Package 'System.ValueTuple 4.4.0' from source
> 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': This package is signed but not
> by a trusted signer.
> /var/tmp/postsharp/cache/DependencyRestore/6.0.101/net6.0-sdk6.0.101-osx-x64--ps6.10.6.0-cf0d89f.deps.proj
> : error NU3037: Package 'System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData
> 4.4.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository primary signature validity period has expired.

My project is targeting framework NetCore3.1.  I don't know why PostSharp mentions net6.0.

As soon as I remove the PostSharp packages, it compiles fine.

Any help, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have .NET 6.0 SDK installed on the machine and it is the active SDK (the highest version is usually used by default). PostSharp always executes under the runtime associated with the current SDK.

You should use [the `global.json` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json?tabs=netcore3x) to specify SDK for .NET Core 3.1. This would cause PostSharp to run on .NET Core 3.1.

If this does not help, it means that PostSharp's dependency packages cannot be installed from nuget.org.

You can disable PostSharp's dependency restore by setting DependencyRestoreDisabled=True (either as env var or MSBuild property) and make sure that the project that was generated into `/var/tmp/postsharp/cache/DependencyRestore/<SdkVersion>/<id>.proj` has all it's dependencies present in the `\var\tmp\postsharp\NuGetFallback` directory.

Disabling the dependency restore disables automated checks and presumes that PostSharp can find all its dependencies on the machine.

Comment: Added a global.json to point at 3.1.  That... helped, but still no dice.  Renamed my sample project and solution, no naming overlap.

Answer (score 0):

I added the global.json, removed SDK 6.x. Set  PostSharpDependencyRestoreDisabled=True and then I had to manually add all the referenced Nuget packages.  It was annoying, but at least it works now.

Daniel, wetween both your responses, I was able to get it fixed!

Thanks!

Comment: No problem, we will have a look at this. Do you have any special settings on your Mac, repo, nuget.config etc.? It is possible to install these packages in a normal project (e.g. `System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData 4.4.0`) or does the restore fail in the same way?

Comment: Very vanilla install.  Nothing overridden.  My only "guess" is that I started to tryout PostSharp a year or two ago, and there is some baggage somewhere leftover from that.

Comment: This does not seem like that. These errors are coming from NuGet restore which PostSharp is running on a generated project file. It's possible that there is some other NuGet configuration active on the `/var/tmp/postsharp/`. Have you tried restoring the generated project file on the above-mentioned path?

Comment: So I need to run "nuget restore /var/tmp/postsharp" ?  Sorry, I've only added/removed packages via VS.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that when PostSharp's MSBuild task runs the "special restore" it may be running with a different NuGet configuration than when you run NuGet restore your project. With the project I was referring to the path from your original post, where PostSharp is restoring the generated project `/var/tmp/postsharp/cache/DependencyRestore/6.0.101/net6.0-sdk6.0.101-osx-x64--ps6.10.6.0-cf0d89f.deps.proj`. I wonder whether you get the same error when you run `dotnet msbuild /t:restore <path>` manually.

Comment: When is Postsharp going to support .Net 6.x?

Comment: PostSharp 6.10 supports .NET 6.0, the first stable version was released in December.

Comment: I have a sample project using 6.10, and it will NOT compile.  Is this an issue because I'm using VS for Mac?

Comment: I understand, is this the same problem as before? Have you tried to manually run the restore command as suggested above?

Comment: I installed net6 previously trying to fix this.  dotnet msbuild /t:restore /var/tmp/postsharp/cache/DependencyRestore/5.0.406/net5.0-sdk5.0.406-osx-x64--ps6.10.8.0-8a73787.deps.proj
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.2+b60ddb6f4 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored /var/tmp/postsharp/cache/DependencyRestore/5.0.406/net5.0-sdk5.0.406-osx-x64--ps6.10.8.0-8a73787.deps.proj (in 1.78 sec).  Recompiling... same errors.

Comment: If the restore of this generated project works if you run it in shell and not when PostSharp executes it (it also executes dotnet restore), it means that some environment variable from the current process (msbuild) is leaking to the restore process and changing NuGet behavior. We have not encountered this yet - it would be best if you could file a bug report on our support site (support.postsharp.net), so that we can get logs. As a workaround, you can create an empty file on path `/var/tmp/postsharp/cache/DependencyRestore/net5.0-sdk5.0.406-osx-x64--ps6.10.8.0-8a73787.touch`.